# Angular 5 new, clean project, Firefox error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5

I created a new project named company, like angular.io tutorial says.

```
ng company

cd company

ng serve --host example.com
```

When I open example.com:4200 with chrome it works fine.
when I try with Firefox, I get the following error in console:

[image]
**UPDATE: Error as text:**

```
[WDS] Disconnected!                                          index.js:176:5
close                           webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js:176:5

onclose                                                      socket.js:17

[5]</EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent                     sockjs.js:170

[14]</</SockJS.prototype._close/<                            sockjs.js:965

ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask                              zone.js:421

Zone.prototype.runTask                                         zone.js:188

ZoneTask.invokeTask                                             zone.js:496

ZoneTask/this.invoke                                            zone.js:485

timer                                                          zone.js:2054
```

Firefox version: 59.0.2 (64 bits)

The project is new, I didn't add any line of code, it just disconnects in firefox.

When I created the project I got these warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/

npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead.

npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained

npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained

npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g
```

I tried to install e newer version of socks, but didn't help:

Any ideas why it gets disconnected?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to `ng serve` only without the `--host` flag? And access with localhost:4200.

Comment: You've got no error on the terminal console when it disconnects from firefox?

Comment: The files are not on my local computer. They are placed on a local server inside the office network.

Comment: No error when disconnects, the terminal shows: Compiled successfully and remains that way.

Comment: Look like webpack disconnect due to binding with host. Try to run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80

Comment: Port 80 is already in use (nginx)

Comment: Could you please post your whole error trace as text, not as picture ?

Comment: Then change port something else 4200 or 8080 or whatever you want

Comment: @trichetriche I added the trace as text.

Comment: @AlokeT I tried with port 4300, compiles perfectly but gets disconnected as before. Could be something from sock.js?